# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf') , I am facing this error when I refresh the Page in React

Tags: redux, react-hooks, react-router

I need to populate the data in the form, I am getting the data but I am facing this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

In useEffect I am using the "indexOf" to populate the data in form. I am able to bind the data to the Form, But If I Refresh the page then I am getting "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')"

```
    let dispatch = useDispatch();
    let history = useHistory();
    let id =useParams().id;
    const [checkBoxes, setcheckBoxes] = useState([
        {name:"Vegetables",isChecked:false},
        {name:"Fruits",isChecked:false},
        {name:"Veg & Fruits",isChecked:false},
        {name:"Only-Veg",isChecked:false},
        {name:"Only-Fruits",isChecked:false}
    ])
    
        const [radio, setradio] = useState([
            {name:"Juice",isChecked:false},
            {name:"Curry",isChecked:false}
        ])

    const gettingSingleData = useSelector((state)=>{
             return state.FetchALLProducts;
    })

    //console.log(gettingSingleData.singleproduct);

     useEffect(() => {

       dispatch(allActions.singleProduct(id));

        let newCheckBoxes = [...checkBoxes]
             newCheckBoxes.forEach((obj)=>{
                obj.isChecked = gettingSingleData.singleproduct.checkes.indexOf(obj.name) > -1
             })
             setcheckBoxes(newCheckBoxes)
     },[id])


    const updateInput=()=>{

    }
    
    const handleCheckChnage =(cb) =>{
          let allcheckboxes = [...checkBoxes];
           allcheckboxes.forEach((obj)=>{
                 if(obj.name === cb.name){
                       if(cb.isChecked){
                           cb.isChecked = false
                       }else{
                           cb.isChecked= true
                       }
                 }
           })
          setcheckBoxes(allcheckboxes);
    }

    const hanldeGenderChange =()=>{

    }

   // updateImage
   let updateImage = async (event) => {
    let imageFile = event.target.files[0];
    let base64Image = await convertBase64String(imageFile);
    dispatch(updateInput(event.target.name , base64Image));
};

let convertBase64String = (imageFile) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
        fileReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
            if(fileReader.result){
                resolve(fileReader.result);
            }
            else {
                reject('Error Occurred');
            }
        })
    });
};

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {/* <h1>LordShiva</h1> */}

               {
                   gettingSingleData.loading ?
                   <React.Fragment>
                        <img src={spinner} alt="" className="d-block m-auto"/>
                    </React.Fragment> : 
                     <section className="p-3">
                     <div className="container">
                         <div className="row">
                             <div className="col animated zoomIn">
                                 <p className="h3 text-secondary">Update a Product</p>
                                 {/* <p className="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid amet consequuntur, corporis, cumque dolore ea enim esse eveniet exercitationem fugit in iste itaque necessitatibus nemo nisi officiis qui totam. Explicabo!</p> */}
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>

                     <div className="container">
                         <div className="row">
                             <div className="col-md-4">
                                 <div className="card animated zoomInLeft delay-1s">
                                     <div className="card-header bg-secondary text-white">
                                         <p className="h4">Update Product</p>
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="card-body rgba-purple-light">
                                         <form >
                                             <div className="form-group">
                                                 <input
                                                     name="name"
                                                     value={gettingSingleData.singleproduct.name}
                                                     onChange={updateInput}
                                                     required type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Product Name"/>
                                             </div>
                                             <div className="form-group">
                                                 <div className="custom-file">
                                                     <input
                                                         name="image"
                                                         onChange={updateImage}
                                                         type="file" className="custom-file-input" id="customFile"/>
                                                     <label className="custom-file-label" htmlFor="customFile">
                                                         {
                                                             gettingSingleData.singleproduct.image !== '' ?
                                                                 <img src={gettingSingleData.singleproduct.image} alt="" width="25" height="25"/> :
                                                                 <span>Product Image</span>
                                                         }
                                                     </label>
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>
                                             <div className="form-group">
                                                 <input
                                                     name="price"
                                                     value={gettingSingleData.singleproduct.price}
                                                     onChange={updateInput}
                                                     required type="number" className="form-control" placeholder="Price"/>
                                             </div>
                                             <div className="form-group">
                                                 <input
                                                     name="qty"
                                                     value={gettingSingleData.singleproduct.qty}
                                                     onChange={updateInput}
                                                     required type="number" className="form-control" placeholder="Available Qty"/>
                                             </div>
                                             <div className="form-group">
                                                <textarea
                                                    name="info"
                                                    value={gettingSingleData.singleproduct.info}
                                                    onChange={updateInput}
                                                    required className="form-control" rows='2'  placeholder="Product Info"/>
                                             </div>
                                             <div>
                                             <div className="form-group mt-3">
                                    <label className="mb-2 fw-bold">Check One</label>
                                     {
                                          checkBoxes.map((cb,i)=>
                                          <div className="form-check">
                                         <label className="form-check-label" >{cb.name}</label>
                                        <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checking" value={cb.name} checked={cb.isChecked} onChange={()=>{handleCheckChnage(cb)}} />
                                      </div>
                                      ) 
                                     }
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group mt-3">
                                    <label className="mb-2 fw-bold">Prepare</label>
                                    {
                                       radio.map((rd)=>(
                                           
                                        <div className="form-check">
                                            <label className="form-check-label" >{rd.name}</label>
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="prepare" value={rd.name} checked={rd.isChecked} onChange={(e) => {hanldeGenderChange(e)}} />
                                       </div>    
                                       ))
                                    }
                                    </div>
                                                 <input type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" value="Update"/>
                                             </div>
                                         </form>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </section>
               }

                <div style={{marginBottom : '150px'}}/>
            </React.Fragment>
```

FetchAllProducts coming from Redux store and it is another Component

```
 let dispatch = useDispatch();
          let history = useHistory();
          let getAlldatafromserver = useSelector((state)=>{
                     return state.FetchALLProducts;
          })

    
       const handleUpdate =(product) =>{
            //console.log(product);
            dispatch(allActions.singleProduct(product))
            history.push(`/updateproduct/${product.id}`);
           
       }
            <button onClick={()=>{handleUpdate(product)}} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Update</button>
```

Comment: Please clean your indentation and also provide where `FetchALLProducts` is defined and populated.

Comment: @samthecodingman Please find the Updated Code and Update bUtton is in Another Component and FetchAllProducts coming from redux Store... Can you please help me , Where I doing Mistake

Comment: Without the code that actually sets the value of `FetchAllProducts`, there's not much we can do. `gettingSingleData.singleproduct.checkes` is `undefined`, but it's unclear why.